# Logging using Enterprise library 5.0 via MSMQ

Tags: .net, msmq, enterprise-library-5

I am using MSMQ trace listener to log messages using Enterprise Library 5.0.
Successfully able to log messages to queue.

What I am unable to figure is how to read the queued messages and log it to Database.
Searched at many places. But did not find any relevant sources.

Can anyone help ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Distributor Service to listen to a queue for messages and then log those messages to the database based on the service configuration file.  See [Using the Distributor Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664428(v=pandp.50).aspx) for details on how to use the service.

One caveat is to make sure all messages are formatted with the BinaryLogFormatter.